# Flutter app lags, then crashes due to high ram usage when running basic Firestore query

Tags: android, flutter, performance, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have  been stuck on this issue for 4 days so far with no progression at all. I have a basic  Firestore query that checks a collection of usernames for the current user's id. However, this seems to make the app lag once the function is run, and depending on how much is on the screen, will sometimes crash the app. Commenting out the section causes the app to continue without any issues.

```
  getUserData() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('userNames')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((value) {
        setState(() {
          email = value["email"];
          deviceToken = value["deviceToken"];
          firstName = value["firstName"];
          lastName = value["lastName"];
          timestamp = value["timestamp"];
          date = value["date"];
          time = value["time"];
          institution = value["institution"];
          address = value["address"];
          points = value["points"];
          institutionName = value["institutionName"];
          placeID = value["placeID"];
          isAdmin = value["isAdmin"];
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

However, this seemingly innocent block of code gives me this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
D/FlutterGeolocator( 5298): Attaching Geolocator to activity
D/FlutterGeolocator( 5298): Creating service.
D/FlutterGeolocator( 5298): Binding to location service.
D/FlutterGeolocator( 5298): Geolocator foreground service connected
D/FlutterGeolocator( 5298): Initializing Geolocator services
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:62150/ckbrDJQ-5oo=/ws
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter( 5298): Compat change id reported: 183155436; UID 10163; state: DISABLED
I/FirebaseApp( 5298): Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
W/ziparchive( 5298): Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/DynamiteLoader.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive( 5298): Unable to open '/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000002/DynamiteLoader.dm': No such file or directory
I/DynamiteModule( 5298): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:83 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:73
I/DynamiteModule( 5298): Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite
D/FirebaseAuth( 5298): Notifying id token listeners about user ( axjkK5tQEpgmy9hMuq6ZZR3EBNx1 ).
I/FA      ( 5298): App measurement initialized, version: 73000
I/FA      ( 5298): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
I/FA      ( 5298): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
I/FA      ( 5298):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.intentions
E/FA      ( 5298): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See 
E/FA      ( 5298): Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
W/FlutterJNI( 5298): FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once
I/ResourceExtractor( 5298): Found extracted resources res_timestamp-1-1668914362742
W/FlutterJNI( 5298): FlutterJNI.prefetchDefaultFontManager called more than once
W/FlutterJNI( 5298): FlutterJNI.init called more than once
I/FLTFireBGExecutor( 5298): Creating background FlutterEngine instance, with args: [--start-paused, --enable-dart-profiling]
D/EGL_emulation( 5298): eglCreateContext: 0x7f1601e19a10: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 5298): eglCreateContext: 0x7f1601e19590: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/HostConnection( 5298): createUnique: call
D/HostConnection( 5298): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f1601e17610, tid 5405
D/HostConnection( 5298): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_queue_submit_with_commands ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma ANDROID_EMU_hwc_multi_configs GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
D/EGL_emulation( 5298): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f1601e19590: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f18221bd280) (first time)
D/FlutterGeolocator( 5298): Geolocator foreground service connected
D/FlutterGeolocator( 5298): Initializing Geolocator services
I/FLTFireMsgService( 5298): FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService started!
W/DynamiteModule( 5298): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 5298): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 5298): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
E/SurfaceSyncer( 5298): Failed to find sync for id=0
W/Parcel  ( 5298): Expecting binder but got null!
D/nativeloader( 5298): classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86_64:/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86_64:/product/lib64:/system/product/lib64
V/NativeCrypto( 5298): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 295 native methods...
W/mple.intentions( 5298): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller( 5298): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
D/TrafficStats( 5298): tagSocket(162) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
W/mple.intentions( 5298): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
D/EGL_emulation( 5298): app_time_stats: avg=52.62ms min=11.22ms max=358.38ms count=19
W/mple.intentions( 5298): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/scudo   ( 5298): Stats: SizeClassAllocator64: 274M mapped (0M rss) in 393783 allocations; remains 289764
I/scudo   ( 5298):   00 (    64): mapped:    256K popped:    4667 pushed:    4381 inuse:    286 total:   1196 rss:      0K releases:      0 last released:      0K region: 0x7f1571e16000 (0x7f1571e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298):   01 (    32): mapped:    256K popped:   10543 pushed:    2756 inuse:   7787 total:   7852 rss:      0K releases:      0 last released:      0K region: 0x7f1581e0d000 (0x7f1581e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298):   02 (    48): mapped:    512K popped:   19214 pushed:    8892 inuse:  
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 18 (  2096): mapped: 261888K popped:  127954 pushed:       9 inuse: 127945 total: 127945 rss:      0K releases:      1 last released:      8K region: 0x7f1691e12000 (0x7f1691e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 19 (  2576): mapped: 261888K popped:  104104 pushed:       0 inuse: 104104 total: 104104 rss:      0K releases:      0 last released:      0K region: 0x7f16a1e19000 (0x7f16a1e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 20 (  3120): mapped: 261888K popped:   85958 pushed:       6 inuse:  85952 total:  85952 rss:      0K releases:      4 last released:      8K region: 0x7f16b1e0e000 (0x7f16b1e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 21 (  4112): mapped: 261888K popped:   65500 pushed:     283 inuse:  65217 total:  65217 rss:      0K releases:      6 last released:      8K region: 0x7f16c1e0b000 (0x7f16c1e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 22 (  4624): mapped: 261888K popped:   58000 pushed:       5 inuse:  57995 total:  57995 rss:      0K releases:      3 last released:     12K region: 0x7f16d1e16000 (0x7f16d1e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 23 (  7120): mapped: 261888K popped:   37791 pushed:     127 inuse:  37664 total:  37664 rss:      0K releases:     32 last released:      4K region: 0x7f16e1e10000 (0x7f16e1e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 24 (  8720): mapped: 261888K popped:   30755 pushed:       2 inuse:  30753 total:  30753 rss:      0K releases:      3 last released:     28K region: 0x7f16f1e0c000 (0x7f16f1e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 25 ( 11664): mapped: 261888K popped:   22995 pushed:       4 inuse:  22991 total:  22991 rss:      0K releases:      6 last released:     52K region: 0x7f1701e17000 (0x7f1701e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 26 ( 14224): mapped: 261888K popped:   18857 pushed:       4 inuse:  18853 total:  18853 rss:      0K releases:      2 last released:     56K region: 0x7f1711e16000 (0x7f1711e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 27 ( 16400): mapped: 261888K popped:   16355 pushed:       3 inuse:  16352 total:  16352 rss:      0K releases:      6 last released:     56K region: 0x7f1721e1a000 (0x7f1721e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 28 ( 18448): mapped: 261888K popped:   14536 pushed:       0 inuse:  14536 total:  14536 rss:      0K releases:      0 last released:      0K region: 0x7f1731e0e000 (0x7f1731e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298):   29 ( 23056): mapped:    512K popped:      15 pushed:       2 inuse:     13 total:     15 rss:      0K releases:      4 last released:     60K region: 0x7f1741e0b000 (0x7f1741e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298):   30 ( 29456): mapped:    768K popped:      25 pushed:       3 inuse:     22 total:     25 rss:      0K releases:      5 last released:     76K region: 0x7f1751e0d000 (0x7f1751e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298):   31 ( 33296): mapped:    768K popped:     224 pushed:     207 inuse:     17 total:     19 rss:      0K releases:      8 last released:     60K region: 0x7f1761e19000 (0x7f1761e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298):   32 ( 65552): mapped:   3328K popped:      58 pushed:       9 inuse:     49 total:     51 rss:      0K releases:      1 last released:     60K region: 0x7f1771e16000 (0x7f1771e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): Scudo OOM: The process has exhausted 256M for size class 18448.
I/scudo   ( 5298): Stats: SizeClassAllocator64: 3591M mapped (0M rss) in 1149236 allocations; remains 1045126
I/scudo   ( 5298):   00 (    64): mapped:    256K popped:    4667 pushed:    4472 inuse:    195 total:   1196 rss:      0K releases:      0 last released:      0K region: 0x7f1571e16000 (0x7f1571e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298):   01 (    32): mapped:    256K popped:   10543 pushed:    2756 inuse:   7787 total:   7852 rss:      0K releases:      0 last released:      0K region: 0x7f1581e0d000 (0x7f1581e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298):   02 (    48): mapped:    512K popped:   19214 pushed:    8892 inuse:  10322 total:  10608 rss:      0K releases:      0 last released:      0K region: 0x7f1591e11000 (0x7f1591e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298):   03 (    64): mapped:    768K popped:   12716 pushed:    2600 inuse:  10116 total:  10220 rss:      0K releases:      0 last released:      0K region: 
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 24 (  8720): mapped: 261888K popped:   30755 pushed:       2 inuse:  30753 total:  30753 rss:      0K releases:      3 last released:     28K region: 0x7f16f1e0c000 (0x7f16f1e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 25 ( 11664): mapped: 261888K popped:   22995 pushed:       4 inuse:  22991 total:  22991 rss:      0K releases:      6 last released:     52K region: 0x7f1701e17000 (0x7f1701e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 26 ( 14224): mapped: 261888K popped:   18857 pushed:       4 inuse:  18853 total:  18853 rss:      0K releases:      2 last released:     56K region: 0x7f1711e16000 (0x7f1711e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 27 ( 16400): mapped: 261888K popped:   16355 pushed:       3 inuse:  16352 total:  16352 rss:      0K releases:      6 last released:     56K region: 0x7f1721e1a000 (0x7f1721e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 28 ( 18448): mapped: 261888K popped:   14536 pushed:       0 inuse:  14536 total:  14536 rss:      0K releases:      0 last released:      0K region: 0x7f1731e0e000 (0x7f1731e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 29 ( 23056): mapped: 261888K popped:   11633 pushed:       2 inuse:  11631 total:  11631 rss:      0K releases:      4 last released:     60K region: 0x7f1741e0b000 (0x7f1741e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 30 ( 29456): mapped: 261888K popped:    9107 pushed:       3 inuse:   9104 total:   9104 rss:      0K releases:      5 last released:     76K region: 0x7f1751e0d000 (0x7f1751e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 31 ( 33296): mapped: 261888K popped:    8261 pushed:     207 inuse:   8054 total:   8054 rss:      0K releases:      8 last released:     60K region: 0x7f1761e19000 (0x7f1761e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): F 32 ( 65552): mapped: 261888K popped:    4100 pushed:       9 inuse:   4091 total:   4091 rss:      0K releases:      1 last released:     60K region: 0x7f1771e16000 (0x7f1771e0a000)
I/scudo   ( 5298): Scudo OOM: The process has exhausted 256M for size class 65552.
I/scudo   ( 5298): Scudo ERROR: internal map failure (NO MEMORY) requesting 4KB
F/libc    ( 5298): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 5334 (1.ui), pid 5298 (mple.intentions)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone64_x86_64/emu64xa:13/TPB4.220624.004/8808248:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86_64'
Timestamp: 2022-11-19 22:20:11.322433000-0500
Process uptime: 48s
Cmdline: com.example.intentions
pid: 5298, tid: 5334, name: 1.ui  >>> com.example.intentions <<<
uid: 10163
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Scudo ERROR: internal map failure (NO MEMORY) requesting 4KB'
    rax 0000000000000000  rbx 00000000000014b2  rcx 00007f181b10968f  rdx 0000000000000006
    r8  0000000000000000  r9  0000000000000000  r10 00007f14fd4ece50  r11 0000000000000207
    r12 0000000000000004  r13 00007f14d0937000  r14 00007f14fd4ece48  r15 00000000000014d6
    rdi 00000000000014b2  rsi 00000000000014d6
    rbp 0000000000001000  rsp 00007f14fd4ece40  rip 00007f181b10968f
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000005f68f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+191) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
      #01 pc 0000000000048d65  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::die()+5) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
      #02 pc 00000000000486c0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::dieOnMapUnmapError(unsigned long)+160) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
      #03 pc 0000000000048e08  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::map(void*, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long, scudo::MapPlatformData*)+152) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
      #04 pc 000000000004ca89  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::MapAllocator<scudo::AndroidConfig>::allocate(scudo::Options, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long*, scudo::FillContentsMode)+457) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
      #05 pc 000000000004aab4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::allocate(unsigned long, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, bool)+948) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
      #06 pc 000000000004ae09  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo_malloc+25) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
      #07 pc 0000000000045877  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (malloc+23) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
      #08 pc 0000000001b3b32c  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #09 pc 0000000001adf34e  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #10 pc 0000000001baf1e9  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #11 pc 0000000001bb0eaf  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #12 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #13 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #14 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #15 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #16 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #17 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #18 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #19 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #20 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #21 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #22 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #23 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #24 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #25 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #26 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #27 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #28 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #29 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #30 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #31 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #32 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #33 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #34 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #35 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #36 pc 0000000001bb0c90  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #37 pc 0000000001bb1164  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #38 pc 0000000001baf765  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #39 pc 0000000001bb1d49  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #40 pc 0000000001da673a  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #41 pc 0000000001d838d5  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #42 pc 0000000001d7f57f  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #43 pc 0000000001d88149  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #44 pc 0000000001d808d1  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #45 pc 0000000001d80f91  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #46 pc 0000000001d81479  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #47 pc 0000000001d928ce  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #48 pc 0000000001c88d09  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #49 pc 0000000001c89d21  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #50 pc 0000000001c8aa36  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #51 pc 0000000001c8a5d9  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #52 pc 0000000001ba8706  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #53 pc 0000000001c890ea  /data/app/~~sT3s6KmnD_GrJo71AVL9sA==/com.example.intentions-xTjSsWwtXQ6xrudeTF1jeQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: b19d2b3189fb7c988d90df73622911a55f5aa88f)
      #54 pc 0000000000002582  [anon:dart-codespace]
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have noticed that this issue began to popup directly after setting up Google Admob. I followed this codelab and have since traced my steps backward and restored to a previous version, but my app continues to act this way. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-ads-in-flutter#0

I have also tried to revert to older versions of all firebase and firestore packages, but I still get this error. Here are all my packages.

Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: intentions
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  email_validator: ^2.1.17
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  date_format: ^2.0.6
  intl: ^0.17.0
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  places_service: ^0.1.2
  google_place: ^0.4.7
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.1
  flutter_neumorphic: ^3.2.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.2.1
  file_picker: ^5.2.1
  open_filex: ^4.1.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  expandable_text: ^2.3.0
  tab_container: ^2.0.0
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.8
  firebase_core: ^1.12.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
  firebase_database: ^9.0.14
  firebase_messaging: ^13.0.4

  firebase_storage: ^10.2.11
  flutter_chip_tags: ^2.0.2
  chips_choice: ^3.0.0
  date_time_picker: ^2.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.9


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/

  fonts:
    - family: cbold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/cbold.otf
    - family: cextrabold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/cextrabold.otf

    - family: clight
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/clight.otf

    - family: cmedium
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/cmedium.otf

    - family: cregular
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/cregular.otf

    - family: csemi
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/csemi.otf

    - family: cthin
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/cthin.otf
    
    - family: urwblack
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/URWGeometricBlack.otf
        
    - family: urwmedium
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/URWGeometricMedium.otf
        
    - family: urwthin
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/URWGeometricThin.otf

    - family: urwsemibold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/URWGeometricSemiBold.otf

    - family: urwregular
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/URWGeometricRegular.otf

    - family: urwlight
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/URWGeometricLight.otf

    - family: urwheavy
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/URWGeometricHeavy.otf

    - family: urwextralight
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/URWGeometricExtraLight.otf

    - family: urwextrabold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/URWGeometricExtraBold.otf

    - family: urwbold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/URWGeometricBold.otf
```

Comment: Btw, I cut out alot of the error log because of the character limit. It's basically just showing the ram is full

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing, you're trying to get the document data and assign the values from it to your local variables, right?

But the `querySnapshot.docs` is actually an object of type `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>>`, which is a list of snapshots for each document, so in order to access the real data of the documents you need to like this:

```
  getUserData() {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('userNames')
      .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((value) {
      setState(() {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = value.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        email = data["email"];
        deviceToken = data["deviceToken"];
        firstName = data["firstName"];
        lastName = data["lastName"];
        timestamp = data["timestamp"];
        date = data["date"];
        time = data["time"];
        institution = data["institution"];
        address = data["address"];
        points = data["points"];
        institutionName = data["institutionName"];
        placeID = data["placeID"];
        isAdmin = data["isAdmin"];
      });
    });
  });
}
```

this will assign the actual data of each document to your variables.

This should work fine.

Comment: The issue still persists

Comment: The issue happens because I set variables that are outside the class. I do it because I want to access those variables outside of the screen, but apparently, waiting to setstate variables that are outside the class causes Firestore to freakout

Comment: I upvoted your answer for the help, but I can't mark it as correct since that would be misleading